# How Can I Retrieve CLOBs for Unique Records in Group By

Tags: oracle

I have a table with one CLOB field (s.File) and I need to create a join on this table to get related data. However, in Oracle, CLOBs are not allowed in group by queries. What is the alternative? I have the following query for which I need to retrieve and serialize the CLOB, but I need the related information as well. See below:

```
select s.FileName, s.File, c.Name as CompanyName
from Source s inner join Company c on s.id = c.id 
group by s.FileName, s.File, c.Name
```

I tried rewriting the query using row_number and partition by, but couldn't get that solution to work either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. The expected results would look something like

- List item

:

```
FileName                File        CompanyName
interestincome.xlsx     CLOB        Woodson Company, Inc.
projectdetails.pdf      CLOB        Johnson Products, LLC
expenses2021.xlsx       CLOB        Marshall Consultants, LLP
```

Comment: Why  are you using `group by` when you have no aggregation? Your title refers to 'unique records' so maybe that's instead of `distinct`, which would have the same problem; but where is the duplication?

Comment: To get around this you can to_char the column if it's < 4000 characters and substr it if it's longer.

Comment: While there is no aggregation, there are many duplicate records in the joined tables. I can remove dupes using group by or distinct keyword, except not when CLOB fields are present. Hence the need for a work-around.

Comment: So the same file (and name) exists multiple times for the same company - assuming company ID is unique? Is there a unique column in the source table?

Comment: Remove duplicates in the `company` table then retrieve single clob per row (if possible) or describe how you want to retrieve more than one clob per company (i.e. where does the duplication arise?)

Comment: @Pugzly Oracle allows 32k `varchar2` in SQL context [for 8 years](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623) (12c goes to the end of life already).

Comment: The real problem is 1) there are no unique records in either table and 2) additional metadata  e.g. FileName is needed from the table that contains the CLOB field, hence the need for the join. I presented a simplified version of a more complex problem, but i'm sure there's a way to get to the data i need because many people have posted similar questions. Unfortunately, their answers have not been entirely helpful for my use case. Just to be clear, are you suggesting using a subquery to retrieve unique company values? if so, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Correction, duplicates are actually in the table that contains the CLOB field. However, there are unique records in that table.

Comment: @astentx I'm aware of 23k limitation in an anonymous block but the question that was posed had to do with grouping a CLOB

Comment: Got it figured out, but thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the unique `CompanyName`/`Filename` combinations and get a single `FILE` (rather than including the files in the `GROUP BY` clause) then:

```sql
SELECT filename,
       (SELECT "FILE" FROM Source f WHERE f.ROWID = min_rowid) AS "FILE",
       companyname
FROM   (
  select s.FileName,
         c.Name as CompanyName,
         MIN(s.ROWID) AS min_rowid
  from   Source s
         inner join Company c
         on s.id = c.id 
  group by
         s.FileName, c.Name
)
```

If you want to check that the files are identical then you can use:

```sql
SELECT filename,
       (SELECT "FILE" FROM Source f WHERE f.ROWID = min_rowid) AS "FILE",
       companyname
FROM   (
  select s.FileName,
         c.Name as CompanyName,
         MIN(s.ROWID) AS min_rowid
  from   Source s
         inner join Company c
         on s.id = c.id 
  group by
         s.FileName,
         c.Name,
         DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(s."FILE", DBMS_CRYPTO.HASHSH256)
)
```

If you want to also consider the unlikely event of hash collisions then you can also compare the start of the files (since any hash collisions are likely to be between files that are not alike):

```sql
SELECT filename,
       (SELECT "FILE" FROM Source f WHERE f.ROWID = min_rowid) AS "FILE",
       companyname
FROM   (
  select s.FileName,
         c.Name as CompanyName,
         MIN(s.ROWID) AS min_rowid
  from   Source s
         inner join Company c
         on s.id = c.id 
  group by
         s.FileName,
         c.Name,
         DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(s."FILE", 1, 4000),
         DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(s."FILE", DBMS_CRYPTO.HASHSH256)
)
```